# with-redefs does not work in specific project on Windows

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, clojure.test

I am having a hard time creating a simple unit test in Clojure using `with-redefs` for mocking on Windows. The test code, the function I'm about to test and the function to be mocked are all in different namespaces/files:

**Function under test:**

```
(ns com.mynamespace.a
  (:require [com.mynamespace.b :as b] ) )

(defn afunc [param] 
  (b/bfunc param))
```

**Dependent b namespace to be mocked out:**

```
  (ns com.mynamespace.b)

  (defn bfunc [param]
    ; External call
  )
```

**Test code**

```
(ns com.mynamespace.a-test
  (:require [com.mynamespace.a :as a]
            [com.mynamespace.b :as b] )
  (:use [clojure.test]))

(deftest a-tests
      (with-redefs [b/bfunc (constantly "dummy")]
        (print (a/afunc "test"))
  )
)
```

I think I use `with-redefs` correctly, because my unit test **runs fine on Linux** machines (docker container or virtual Ubuntu), but it just does not work when executing/developing them on my Windows dev machine: the `with-redefs` bindings are **not applied** and the test wants to make real e.g. http calls, which I'd like to mock. It is the same case if I run `lein test`, or try executing the test from a REPL through Eclipse CCW.

I know with-redefs has some strange behaviour, but as my test works well on Linux, I guess I miss something, when running this project's test on Windows. I would like to achieve fast feedback loops, when writing tests on my Windows machine.

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks,
Andras

Comment: Unable to reproduce with Clojure 1.8.0 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turned out that this issue was specific to a project I'm working on, because of the **-Dclojure.compiler.direct-linking=true** jvm-opts flag.

After turning off direct linking, my tests work on my Windows dev machine as well. I wonder why they passed on Linux though, but perhaps it was not applied, when running `lein test` there.